# C# variables in Sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I am playing with sequence diagram. And main question is how to draw properly  on sequence diagram interaction with variable. How to draw

1) When `MakePayment` aggregates `person`

> insurance.MakePayment(person.FirstName, person.SecondName, 20);

2) Variable assignment

> internalVariable = SecondName;

I am not sure that I draw right sequence.

[image]

```
namespace Example
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string SecondName { get; set; }

        public string Salary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Insurance
    {
        private readonly Bank bank;

        public Insurance()
        {
            bank = new Bank();
        }

        public bool MakePayment(string FirstName, string SecondName, int value)
        {
            if (bank.GetBalance(FirstName, SecondName) > value)
            {

            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Bank
    {
        private string SomeVariable { get; set; }

        private string internalVariable;

        public Bank()
        {

        }

        public decimal GetBalance(string FirstName, string SecondName)
        {
            SomeVariable = FirstName;
            internalVariable = SecondName;
            return 320;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.FirstName = "FirstName";
            person.SecondName = "SecondName";
            Insurance insurance = new Insurance();
            insurance.MakePayment(person.FirstName, person.SecondName, 20);
            PrintResult(person.FirstName);
        }

        public static void PrintResult(string firstName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(firstName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note on terminology.  What you call "internal variable" is usually called "member variable" or "fields".  All member variables combined are referred to as "state" [of an object], even when we aren't discussing a state machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're putting to much information in your diagram. You can of course, but this kind of diagrams are usually used to show, *as simply as possible*, the interactions between actors in a use case.

In this case, the actors would be:

1. The User clicking on the *Make payment* button.
2. The Insured person receiving the money from the insurer.
3. The Insurer.
4. The Bank.

The messages exchanged would be:

1. User to Insurer: Make Payment (Parameter=Insured)
2. Insurer to bank: Get Balance (Parameter=Account)
3. Bank to Insurer: Done (Parameter=Balance)
4. Insurer to bank: Transfer Money (Parameters=Amount, Insurer Account, Insured Account)
5. Bank to Insurer: Done (Parameter=Transaction code)
6. Insurer to User: Done (Parameter=Transaction code)

You could also show on the same diagram the interaction resulting for insufficient funds, or create a new use case for this.

Object creation should not be shown, unless it is crucial (if you want to show how an object factory create an object, for example).